# PHP Goutte - Check if an attribute exists before referencing it

Tags: php, goutte

I have the following code to get the urls of images from a site that I am scraping using the [PHP Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) library.

```
$gClient = new Client();

$crawler = $gClient->request('GET', 'https://somewebsite.org/somepage');

$results = $crawler->filter(
        '.class_id'
    )->each(function ($node, $i) {

        $node->filter('img')->each(function ($im, $k) {
            if ($im->attr('src')) {
                dump($im->attr('src'));
            }
        });
    });
```

There is an obvious flaw here that I don't know how to fix, I have to check if the "src" attribute exists before I call it (otherwise I get a *Call to a member function attr() on null* error), but I don't know how to correct this. I've tried the [property_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function as follows:

```
if (property_exists($im, 'attr("src")') {
...
}
```

but I'm not sure if this even is the right way to do this if the property that you are trying to check is a function..
Does anyone know how to avoid the call to null error here?

Comment: PHP nullsafe operator solved this (new in PHP 8)

Comment: Which line is giving you the error exactly? If `$im->attr('src')` is failing, it's because `$im` is NULL, not because `$im->attr('src')` is NULL. You may also want to first check whether `$im` is NULL: `if ($im) { dump($im->attr('src')); }`.

Answer (score 2):

You may apply try..catch.

```
try {
    echo $im->attr('src');
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo "No 'src' found";
}
```